# How to duplicate columns data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

This is my query:

```
select 
    t.range as [score range], count(*) as [number of occurences]
from 
    (select 
         case 
            when answer_count between 0 and 5 then ' 0- 9'
            when answer_count between 5 and 10 then '10-19'
            else '20-99' end as range
     from 
         points 
     where 
         type = 'product_quiz') t 
group by 
    t.range
```

The output is:

```
/-------------------------------------\
| score range | number of occurrences |
|-------------+-----------------------|
|   10-19     |         121327        |
|    0- 9     |         129195        |
\-------------------------------------/
```

But I want the output like this:

```
/-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| score_range | number_of_occurrences | score_range1 | number_of_occurrences1 |
|-------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------------------|
|   10-19     |         121327        |    10-19     |         121327         |
|    0- 9     |         129195        |     0- 9     |         129195         |
\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

How can I achieve this using a sub-query?

Comment: You're going to need to pivot if you want that output.  But why not have each distinct range as a separate column?

Comment: Why do you need a sub-query? That would seem to add needless complexity, and extra processing overhead. You can achieve what you want with something like `select t.range  as [score_range], count(*) as [number_of_occurences], t.range  as [score_range1], count(*) as [number_of_occurences1] from ...`

Comment: But here my requirement is to use like that..If possible in pivot then  it is quite ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need a subquery (unless you're referring to the subquery already present in your `FROM` clause):

```
select 
    t.range as [score_range], 
    count(*) as [number_of_occurences],
    t.range as [score_range1], 
    count(*) as [number_of_occurences1]
from 
    (select 
         case 
            when answer_count between 0 and 5 then ' 0- 9'
            when answer_count between 5 and 10 then '10-19'
            else '20-99' end as range
     from 
         points 
     where 
         type = 'product_quiz') t 
group by 
    t.range
```

**Why** you would want to do this (and why you would particularly want to use a subquery) is quite another question.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. But My requirement is, i wan to add sub query for number_of_occurences and number_of_occurences1 coloumn not in case

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? If not, let us know what is still wrong and we can give you a better answer.

Comment: No. for ex: i want query like this select 
    t.range as [score_range], 
    (select count (*) from tablename )as [number_of_occurences],
    (select count (*) from tablename1 )as [number_of_occurences1],
from 
   (select 
         case 
            when answer_count between 0 and 5 then ' 0- 9'
            when answer_count between 5 and 10 then '10-19'
            else '20-99' end as range
     from 
         points 
     where 
         type = 'product_quiz') t 
group by 
    t.range i want like this

Comment: Why do you want it like that? What I've given in this answer produces the desired output in your question, so one of us is missing something somewhere...